# Radio button not getting the proper value assigned

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a radio button group that is being rendered dynamically. I have an NgModel assigned to this group and I want that whenever the button is clicked, a function is called that accesses which button is clicked. I added different values to each button but somehow the value being assigned is coming blank. Here is my code:

component.html:

```
<div class="form-group row position-relative" *ngFor="let item of options; let i=index">
        <div class="col-4">
            <label class="text-capitalize">{{item.label}}</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <label class="text-capitalize">{{item.value}}</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <input type="{{builderService.editObj.type}}" name="checked" [value]="item.value" (click)="changeSelectedElement($event)" [(ngModel)]="checkedElement">
        </div>
        <div class="col-1 text-right">
            <i class="fa fa-times pointer" (click)="editService.fnRemove('options', i)"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
```

component.ts:

```
 changeSelectedElement(e){
    console.log('this.checkedElement -------> ', this.checkedElement, e.target.value);
   }
```

The log statement logs a blank value:

```
this.checkedElement ------->
```

I need to access the item.value of each radio button here. The items are being printed properly when using string interpolation so no, item.value is not blank.

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using codesandbox.

Comment: Can you share the component ts files as well

Comment: Why are  you repeating ```<label>``` twice with different values?